# Fields not displaying in SSRS report using Display method

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-ax-2012, axapta, ax

I am trying to display the field in the SSRS report using the Display method. I created a display method in a table which returns the required value. I then selected that display method as the field in the report. It does not show any value in the report which are generated using Display method.

Comment: @Jeroen a "Display Method" is a specific type of method in AX, which Alok has tagged

Comment: @AnthonyBlake my bad, comment obsolete so I removed it.

Comment: It's painfully obvious but:  Ensure that the table being used in the SSRS dataset is the same one that you have added to the table buffer.  Also on the SSRS datasource child node perform a Refresh to synchronise changes between AX and SSRS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. In my case it was because display method was not returning anything because of logical error. I was not able to debug this by directly using the breakpoints and debugger so I had to create a job to debug the display method and figure out the problem.